# AJAX and asp.net security question

Tags: asp.net, javascript, wcf, security

I have a couple of questions regarding security mechanisms in asp.net (2.0).

I have always been using Forms authentication +  Page.User for validating permissions.

Now I need to send some data from client side javaScript (jQuery) to a WCF service.
Will my IPrincipal be still accessible from HttpContext of WCF service (I'm hosting my services on same IIS, same domain).

I'm particulary interested if $.Ajax will grab client authentication cookie and assign it to HttpContext on the server (or does it happen automagically)?

What are possible gotchas / pitfalls here?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. Are you trying to login using WCF or just perform a priviledged operation via WCF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but need to set this property in web.config of your WCF service.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```